# Byte typecasting

Tags: java

It is a basic question, but I couldn't get a the proper answer.  I am thinking it is because of primitive types auto type casting

Why would the below statement invokes the print(int x) method and not print (char x) method.

```
public class Overloading {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        byte b='x';
        print(b);
    }

    public static void print(int x)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside int Print "+x);
    }


    public static void print(char x)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside char Print "+x);
    }

    public static void print(float x)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside float Print "+x);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conversion that may be used for this [method invocation conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) is a [widening primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) :

> byte to short, int, long, float, or double
>
> short to int, long, float, or double
>
> char to int, long, float, or double
>
> int to long, float, or double
>
> long to float or double
>
> float to double

You see there is no `byte` to `char` path. This isn't a priority matter : if you remove the function taking an `int` as parameter, your code won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

`byte` will auto convert to `int` not to `char`

```
 primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:    

    byte to short, int, long, float, or double
```

reference [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) section 5.1.2

Answer (score 0):

compiler chooses an overloaded method this way

```
byte->short->int->long
```

interestingly, if you leave only `print(char x)` you'll get compiler error

for char it is

```
char->int->long
```